# Strange Null pointer exception case: ternary conditional operator not working with string concatenation

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

```
StringBuffer sb=null;

// Some more logic that conditionally assigns value to the StringBuffer

// Prints Value=null
System.out.println("Value="+sb);

// Throws NullPointerException
System.out.println("Value=" + sb != null ? sb.toString() : "Null");
```

The fix for this issue is encompassing the ternary operator in brackets:

```
// Works fine
System.out.println("Value=" + (sb != null ? sb.toString() : "Null"));
```

How is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `+` has a higher [precedence](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/what-is-java-operator-precedence.html) than a `!=`.

So you evalutate `"(Value="+sb ) != null` at first.

Comment: @SidCool I just had the exact same problem, thanks for having already asked the question for me :)

Answer (score 6):

Let's bracket the expression the way that the compiler effectively would, in the broken vase:

```
System.out.println( ("Value" + sb != null) ? sb.toString() : "Null");
```

Now `"Value" + sb` will never be null even if `sb` is null... so when `sb` *is* null, it's calling `toString()` and going bang.

Answer (score 4):

I think the issue is that the statement is being parsed like this:

```
System.out.println( ("Value="+sb) != null ? sb.toString() : "Null" );
```

The string concatenation operator (+) has a heigher precedence than the ternary operator.

Since "Value"+null is always not null, sb.toString() will always be called, even if sb is null, hence the NullPointerException.

If in doubt - parenthesize!  Even if not in doubt! :)

Answer (score 2):

The ternary operation bypasses the toString method on the null object, which is what is causing the NullPointerException.

Comment: If it bypasses, then it should not cause a NullPointerException, right?  Sorry if I got you wrong.

Comment: Yes, it never calls the method toString on the null object. If you call a method on a null object (sb), it causes a NullPointerException.

Comment: I feel dumb after this.  This was so logical.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the exception is cause when sb.toString() gets executed.

In the fix you check if sb is null before executing so the offending call is not attempted.

Answer (score 0):

System.out.print() is implemented like that:

```
public void print(String s) {
        if (s == null) {
            s = "null";
        }
        write(s);
}
```

With sb = null, `sb.toString()` means `null.toString()` which leads to you NullPointerException